# UNKNOWN process when ending user session

Tags: 10.04, shutdown, ubuntu-netbook, restart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out which “Unknown” program is still running and preventing shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62820/how-to-find-out-which-unknown-program-is-still-running-and-preventing-shutdown)

This process sometimes shows up when shutting down and it never ends in cases its showing up. Rarely but this comes up
Ubuntu Netbook Remix 10.04.03

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you please add more information to your question please?